# How to run command every time when the server is running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, daemon

I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04.

I want to run specific command every time when the server starts. I mean that this command should be executed **when the server runs** (continually working).

This command is connected to PHP framework and starts a web application. Normally I can run this command by going to the folder where the app is located `/var/www/html/app` and then I execute `php artisan serve --host ipadress`

Comment: You have many choices: systemd, upstart or systemctl.

Comment: Ok, but could you give me some example how to run this command firstly entering to the directory and then run this command?

Comment: see the `chdir`, `exec` and `setuid/setgid` in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some programs are not designed to be run with continuous user input and disconnect from the terminal at the first opportunity. For example, a web server responds to web requests, rather than user input. Mail servers are another example of this type of application. These types of programs are known as daemons. The term daemon comes from Greek mythology and represents an entity that is neither good nor evil, and which invisibly performs useful tasks. This is why the BSD mascot is the cheerful-looking daemon with sneakers and a pitchfork.

Let using upstart:

Create a file named: /etc/init/my-http-server.conf

```
description "my-http-server"

start on (filesystem)
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
#setuid my_user_id
#setgid my_group_id
#chdir /opt/my/env

exec <your command>

pre-start script
  mkdir -p /var/run/my/
  chown -R my:www-data /var/run/my  
end script

#post-start script
#  sleep 6
#  chmod 776 /var/run/my/.s.my
#end script
```

For more information refer to : [upstart documents](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html).

Then use `start`/`stop`/`restart` commands to control your daemon:

```
$ start my-http-server
$ stop my-http-server
$ restart my-http-server
```

For a complete list of available choices to make a daemon process on ubuntu 16.04: see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)

**EDIT 1:**
I have some additional info: The ubuntu 16.04 comes with [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd).

So, the best practice is to make a systemd daemon. because the rc.d, init.d and upstart will be deprecated very soon!.

Comment: I did it, but unfortunetly when I start my-http-server I'm getting this: `start: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/ups`

Comment: its up to your configurations. check permissions and paths in ypur application config. and do not use: `pre-start script` and `post-start script`. it's just for example.

Comment: It's highly recommended to read up the upstart documentation carefully. and: DO NOT DO ANYTHING IF YOU DON'T KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING

Comment: Now I don't know what to do. I should remove the "pre-start script" totally and then what?

Comment: Then read the upstart documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `cron` entry using `@reboot` for that purpose. It will be executed once at startup.

You can either put a file into `/etc/cron.d` with this content:

```
 @reboot    root    cd /var/www/html/app && /usr/bin/php artisan serve --host ipaddress
```

You should change root to a different user if the command doesn't need root privileges.

Alternatively you can run `crontab -e -u username`  to edit the crontab of the user which should execute the command and insert this line into it:

```
 @reboot    cd /var/www/html/app && /usr/bin/php artisan serve --host ipaddress
```

Because of the `&&` the command is only executed if the `cd` was successful.

**Update**: If it is a server process, you are better off using an init system like pylover indicated. I would prefer systemd on ubuntu because they just changed to it and i'm not sure how long the others (upstart) will be available without having to install or configure anything. An init system gives you the benefit of being able to start and stop the service and query its status.

Comment: Okay, it looks nice, but where to put this code? I am newbie in linux.

Comment: This is the cheapest way to do that, a regular and perfect solution is daemons.

Comment: You're right. I read it as if it was a one time job. Servers shouldn't be started using cron.

Comment: I've created file in /etc/cron.d/laravel and paste this command, nothing happens.